# Why does lspci show intel 8th gen when I am using i7-9850H cpu?

Tags: cpu, intel, acpi, pci, cpu-architecture

OS: Debian 10

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo

model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9850H CPU @ 2.60GHz

$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 0d)
```

I think i7-9850H is intel 9th gen core processor. But why does lspci show `8th Gen`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lspci uses a community driven [PCI database](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/) which might contain errors.

You may want to download its latest version and overwrite your Debian file (it's 100% safe) and see if the error has been fixed. If not, please submit new correct information.

Another possibility is that this particular device is shared between 8th generation and 9th generation CPUs, so it's shown to be the 8th generation though I've never seen Intel do this before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have updated the file at `/usr/share/misc/pci.ids`. But `lspci` still shows `8th gen`. For some reasons, I can not reboot my device now. So I don't know if the result will change after reboot or not. The cpu has stepping 13. It might not be a released version. I am not sure if this can be the cause or not.

Comment: Debian even has a handy command to update the database, `update-pciids` (run it as root).

Comment: @StephenKitt I like Fedora's approach - for all Fedora versions they always push the latest version of this file. No matter your Fedora version is, you at least can always identify your devices even if your PC is brand new.

Comment: @Artem indeed, and Fedora’s package update policy is more flexible than Debian’s which helps in this case ;-).